# Python groupby is missing first element of each group

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a nested list that I need to verify that the data is presented by a sort on column 2 (Severity of a ticket), then a reverse chronological date sort within each each Severity group.

I think I've nearly reached the proper solution using groupby, however for some reason groupby is dropping the first element in each group. And no amount of coffee is helping my brain to understand why.

```
all_case_data = [
    ('01', 2, '2253415', datetime(2015, 1, 14, 8, 8, 18), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('02', 3, '3824819', datetime(2015, 4, 9, 14, 38, 54), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('03', 3, '3824715', datetime(2015, 4, 9, 6, 6, 7), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('04', 3, '3824707', datetime(2015, 4, 9, 5, 55, 27), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('05', 3, '3824549', datetime(2015, 4, 8, 6, 7, 7), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('06', 3, '3824061', datetime(2015, 4, 7, 15, 31, 26), 'Updated', 'user1'),
    ('07', 3, '3822989', datetime(2015, 3, 24, 5, 29, 50), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('08', 3, '3822385', datetime(2015, 3, 20, 6, 2, 44), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('09', 3, '3822377', datetime(2015, 3, 20, 5, 54, 33), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('10', 3, '3820965', datetime(2015, 3, 6, 18, 52, 43), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('11', 3, '3820963', datetime(2015, 3, 6, 18, 50, 10), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('12', 3, '3767961', datetime(2015, 2, 18, 9, 9, 12), 'Updated', 'user1'),
    ('13', 3, '3767841', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 32, 12), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('14', 3, '3767839', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 27, 16), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('15', 3, '3767837', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 24), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('16', 3, '3767835', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 5, 48), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('17', 3, '3767833', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 0, 25), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('18', 3, '3767831', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 57, 11), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('19', 3, '3767803', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 11, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('20', 3, '3767809', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 7, 45), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('21', 3, '3767801', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 18, 10), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('22', 3, '3767807', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 50, 40), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('23', 3, '3767805', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 16, 41), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('24', 3, '2257019', datetime(2015, 2, 10, 8, 36, 13), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('25', 3, '2256663', datetime(2015, 2, 8, 18, 47, 48), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('26', 3, '2252573', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 32, 12), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('27', 3, '2252571', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 27, 31), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('28', 3, '2252569', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 24), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('29', 3, '2252531', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('30', 3, '2252533', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 16, 41), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('31', 3, '2252535', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 11, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('32', 3, '2252539', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 7, 45), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('33', 3, '2252567', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 5, 48), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('34', 3, '2252565', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 1, 7), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('35', 3, '2252563', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 57, 29), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('36', 3, '2252537', datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 50, 59), 'Pending', 'user1'),
    ('37', 3, '1168027', datetime(2014, 9, 7, 10, 4, 4), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('38', 4, '3824817', datetime(2015, 4, 9, 14, 35, 36), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('39', 4, '3824717', datetime(2015, 4, 9, 6, 14, 6), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('40', 4, '3824709', datetime(2015, 4, 9, 5, 56, 55), 'New', 'user1'),
    ('41', 4, '3824065', datetime(2015, 4, 7, 15, 37, 45), 'Updated', 'user1'),
    ('42', 4, '3824063', datetime(2015, 4, 2, 8, 42, 43), 'New', 'user1'),
]
from itertools import groupby
import operator
# Create new list composed of initial list, but sorted by Severity
all_case_data_sorted_by_severity = sorted(all_case_data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
# Leveraging groupby, create a new list composed of sorted data, sorted in reverse chronological order within each group
groups = []   # Contains list of sub-lists grouped by the unique key (Severity)
uniquekeys = []  # Contains concise list of all of the unique keys (Severity)
# Note: groupby requires the list to first be sorted by the key (Severity) so use all_case_data_sorted_by_severity
for key, group in groupby(all_case_data_sorted_by_severity, operator.itemgetter(1)):   # x[1] = Severity
    for thing in group:
        groups.append(sorted(list(group), key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True))  # Within each group, sort by date
        uniquekeys.append(key)
print "Uniquekeys:", uniquekeys
print "Groups:", groups
```

Here's the output. Notice I'm missing three elements in Groups. The first element for each unique key is missing, so the first case with Severity 2 (case # 01), first case with Severity 3 (case #02), first case with Severity 4 (case #38).

```
Uniquekeys: [2, 3, 4]
Groups: [[], [('03', 3, '3824715', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 6, 6, 7), 'New', 'user1'), ('04', 3, '3824707', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 5, 55, 27), 'New', 'user1'), ('05', 3, '3824549', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 8, 6, 7, 7), 'New', 'user1'), ('06', 3, '3824061', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7, 15, 31, 26), 'Updated', 'user1'), ('07', 3, '3822989', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 24, 5, 29, 50), 'New', 'user1'), ('08', 3, '3822385', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 20, 6, 2, 44), 'New', 'user1'), ('09', 3, '3822377', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 20, 5, 54, 33), 'New', 'user1'), ('10', 3, '3820965', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 18, 52, 43), 'New', 'user1'), ('11', 3, '3820963', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 18, 50, 10), 'New', 'user1'), ('12', 3, '3767961', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 9, 9, 12), 'Updated', 'user1'), ('24', 3, '2257019', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 10, 8, 36, 13), 'New', 'user1'), ('25', 3, '2256663', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 8, 18, 47, 48), 'New', 'user1'), ('13', 3, '3767841', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 32, 12), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('26', 3, '2252573', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 32, 12), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('27', 3, '2252571', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 27, 31), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('14', 3, '3767839', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 27, 16), 'New', 'user1'), ('29', 3, '2252531', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('15', 3, '3767837', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 24), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('28', 3, '2252569', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 24), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('21', 3, '3767801', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 18, 10), 'New', 'user1'), ('23', 3, '3767805', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 16, 41), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('30', 3, '2252533', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 16, 41), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('19', 3, '3767803', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 11, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('31', 3, '2252535', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 11, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('20', 3, '3767809', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 7, 45), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('32', 3, '2252539', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 7, 45), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('16', 3, '3767835', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 5, 48), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('33', 3, '2252567', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 5, 48), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('34', 3, '2252565', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 1, 7), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('17', 3, '3767833', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 0, 25), 'New', 'user1'), ('35', 3, '2252563', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 57, 29), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('18', 3, '3767831', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 57, 11), 'New', 'user1'), ('36', 3, '2252537', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 50, 59), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('22', 3, '3767807', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 50, 40), 'New', 'user1'), ('37', 3, '1168027', datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 7, 10, 4, 4), 'New', 'user1')], [('39', 4, '3824717', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 6, 14, 6), 'New', 'user1'), ('40', 4, '3824709', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 5, 56, 55), 'New', 'user1'), ('41', 4, '3824065', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7, 15, 37, 45), 'Updated', 'user1'), ('42', 4, '3824063', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 2, 8, 42, 43), 'New', 'user1')]]
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*… I need to verify that the data is presented by a sort …*"  You don't need `groupby` for that, you just need to sort the data:

```
all_case_data_sorted = sorted(
    all_case_data, key = lambda x:(x[1],datetime.max-x[3]))
```

If, for some reason, you can't select a key by negation (as I did above), you can sort multiple times, once for each key. This works because Python sorts are stable:

```
all_case_data_sorted = sorted(all_case_data, key = lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)
all_case_data_sorted = sorted(all_case_data_sorted, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: Awesome. Simple is always so much better. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you're not referring to your iteration variable within a loop, that's often a sign that something's wrong with your logic:

```
for thing in group:
    groups.append(sorted(list(group), key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True))  # Within each group, sort by date
    uniquekeys.append(key)
```

Why are you looping over `group`?  If you remove that loop, it looks like you should get what you want.  That's why you're missing the first element: you're consuming it there, as `thing` is bound to it. Without it, I get (changing the indentation to make it easier to read):

```
Uniquekeys: [2, 3, 4]
Groups: [[('01', 2, '2253415', datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 14, 8, 8, 18), 'New', 'user1')], 
         [('02', 3, '3824819', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 14, 38, 54), 'New', 'user1'), 
          ('03', 3, '3824715', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 6, 6, 7), 'New', 'user1'), [and so on]
```

[Aside: working with tabular data is often made easier by using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org); sorting by severity and reversed date would be `data.sort(["severity", "date"], ascending=[True, False])`, and so on.)

Comment: Correct, removing the loop over group corrects my issue. I'll look into pandas as I'm expecting the data I need to validate to get much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative and a more pythonic way for such problems you can use  `collection.defaultdict` :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in all_case_data :
...    d[i[1]].append(i)
... 
>>> d.keys()
[2, 3, 4]
>>> d.values()
[[('01', 2, '2253415', datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 14, 8, 8, 18), 'New', 'user1')], [('02', 3, '3824819', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 14, 38, 54), 'New', 'user1'), ('03', 3, '3824715', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 6, 6, 7), 'New', 'user1'), ('04', 3, '3824707', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 5, 55, 27), 'New', 'user1'), ('05', 3, '3824549', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 8, 6, 7, 7), 'New', 'user1'), ('06', 3, '3824061', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7, 15, 31, 26), 'Updated', 'user1'), ('07', 3, '3822989', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 24, 5, 29, 50), 'New', 'user1'), ('08', 3, '3822385', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 20, 6, 2, 44), 'New', 'user1'), ('09', 3, '3822377', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 20, 5, 54, 33), 'New', 'user1'), ('10', 3, '3820965', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 18, 52, 43), 'New', 'user1'), ('11', 3, '3820963', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 18, 50, 10), 'New', 'user1'), ('12', 3, '3767961', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 9, 9, 12), 'Updated', 'user1'), ('13', 3, '3767841', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 32, 12), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('14', 3, '3767839', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 27, 16), 'New', 'user1'), ('15', 3, '3767837', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 24), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('16', 3, '3767835', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 5, 48), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('17', 3, '3767833', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 0, 25), 'New', 'user1'), ('18', 3, '3767831', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 57, 11), 'New', 'user1'), ('19', 3, '3767803', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 11, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('20', 3, '3767809', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 7, 45), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('21', 3, '3767801', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 18, 10), 'New', 'user1'), ('22', 3, '3767807', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 50, 40), 'New', 'user1'), ('23', 3, '3767805', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 16, 41), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('24', 3, '2257019', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 10, 8, 36, 13), 'New', 'user1'), ('25', 3, '2256663', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 8, 18, 47, 48), 'New', 'user1'), ('26', 3, '2252573', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 32, 12), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('27', 3, '2252571', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 27, 31), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('28', 3, '2252569', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 24), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('29', 3, '2252531', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 21, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('30', 3, '2252533', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 16, 41), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('31', 3, '2252535', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 11, 27), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('32', 3, '2252539', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 7, 45), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('33', 3, '2252567', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 5, 48), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('34', 3, '2252565', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 6, 1, 7), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('35', 3, '2252563', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 57, 29), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('36', 3, '2252537', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 5, 50, 59), 'Pending', 'user1'), ('37', 3, '1168027', datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 7, 10, 4, 4), 'New', 'user1')], [('38', 4, '3824817', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 14, 35, 36), 'New', 'user1'), ('39', 4, '3824717', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 6, 14, 6), 'New', 'user1'), ('40', 4, '3824709', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 5, 56, 55), 'New', 'user1'), ('41', 4, '3824065', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7, 15, 37, 45), 'Updated', 'user1'), ('42', 4, '3824063', datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 2, 8, 42, 43), 'New', 'user1')]]
```